# Perl regex to find the name of a packed struct without using variable length lookbehind?

Tags: c, regex, perl

I have a number of C structures across several different files.  Some of them are specified as packed, and some are not.  Like this:

```
typedef struct foo_s {
    uint32 foo_field_1;
    uint64 foo_field_2;
} foo_t;

typedef struct bar_s {
    uint32 bar_field_1;
    uint64 bar_field_2;
} __packed bar_t;
```

I'd like to get a list of the struct names for only the packed structs.  For the code above, that would include `bar_s`, but not `foo_s`.

I wrote a Perl one-liner like this that seems to get me most of the way there:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'while(m/typedef struct (\w+) {\n(?:.*\n)*?} __packed \w+;/g){print "$1\n";}' <filename>
```

The issue is that for the structs above, this actually returns foo_s, since it initially matches `typedef struct foo_s {` and then continues until it matches `} __packed bar_t`.

I tried using lookbehind to go back and find the most recent match of `typedef struct` whenever `__packed` is found, but variable length lookbehind is not supported.

Is there a way to handle this with regular expressions in Perl?  Ideally, it would be something like "Match `typedef struct <name>` each time it's found, and then if you find `__packed`, print out the most recently matched struct name".

I'd like to avoid writing a parser if I can.

Thanks!

Comment: So, uhm, you want to parse C, without writing a parser for C? Ain't gonna happen with any amount of robustness, sorry. Better to actually write a parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ perl -0777 -nE 'say $1 while m/typedef struct (\w+) \{[^}]+\} __packed \w+;/g' file
bar_s
```

The keys here is `\{[^}]+\}` to match a braced block with no "inner" close braces.